# SQL Server CE with Entity Framework 6.0: Increase Connection Timeout

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

Is it possible to increase the connection timeout on a SQL Server CE connection? (everything I have found on SO or Google is for SQL Server Express). I am using EF 6.0 to connect to SQL Server CE 4.0 files. I believe the connections are timing out.

I get the following exception:

> The underlying provider failed on Open.

The inner exception reads

> There is a file sharing violation. A different process might be using the file.

I have tried adding `Connect Timeout=30` to the connection string (this is set in the context constructor, because I need to dynamically set the file path), but I get an exception that the "connect timeout" keyword is not recognized.

There is a `ConnectionTimeout` property on `DbContext.Database.Connection` but it is readonly.

Comment: Since SQL Server CE is *not* a server-based system, there's really no *connection* happening - your app just opens the file. But please **read** the error message! It says clearly: *sharing violation* and goes on to say *a different process might be using the file* - so that's the problem - something else is already using that file!

Comment: Make sure to use the exact same connectionstring if connecting to the database file from differnt processes on the same machine

Comment: @marc_s, the connections are all within the same application from a single PC (all from the same EF context class with the application).  This problem has recently arisen when the SQLCE files were moved to a shared drive (on the network).